# Overview and detail Page Database list

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I am currently programming a shop system in PHP in which I want to display the products that are in the database on one page.

At the moment I am trying to display a short description, a picture and a "like"-button it in a square. It's supposed to work like a button - if I click on the picture I'd like to Display the details as a pop up or on a new page.

I've implemented a function that works but only looks like a button. I've not been able to display the picture and the "Like"-button:

```
function getGroup (){

    $get_group = "SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE ShortDescription!='' order by ID DESC";

    $run_group = mysqli_query($link, $get_group);
    while($row_group=mysqli_fetch_array($run_group)){

        $group_id =$row_group["ID"];
        $group_ShortDescription =$row_group["ShortDescription"];
        $group_Plattform =$row_group["Plattform"];

        echo "
          <div id='Single_Group'>
          <a href='details.php?ID=$group_id' class='ui-btn' id='GroupsButton'>$group_ShortDescription <wbr>          $group_Plattform</a>
          </div>
        ";

    }



}
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Try with ajax ?

Comment: You can do it using CSS and Jquery/Ajax ! First, design your visual which is the square with pictures and ..., then add your script to capture the data from database.

Comment: If it's for educational purposes only, you probably will be fine using vanilla PHP, but it does not look like in this case (*"programming a shop system"*)  You should really consider using a framework (e.g. Lavarel, Symfony2). You will burn money (time => money), end up having a hardly-maintainable solution (i.e. lay the foundation to burn more money in the future) and eventually end up with an unsecure product (you know ... burn money) if you don't.